# How to find $x$ of this equation

Tags: logarithms

I am a beginner to logarithms.
By using logarithms, in this equation, I want to find the value of $x$:

$$ \ 3^x = 4^{x-1} \ $$

I am using 10 as base of logarithm.
And I want $x$ in terms of $\log2$ and $\log3$, as far as possible.

Comment: If you are using $10$ as your base of logarithm, why do you want to use $\ln 2$ and $\ln 3$, which are the natural logarithms (base $e$?)

Comment: Note that $(4/3)^x=4$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews It was a silly typing error.. sorry.. I've now edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned logarithm use is desired. Here, for a solution in terms of natural logarithms,
\begin{align}
\ln(3^{x}) &= \ln(4^{x-1}) \\
x \, \ln(3) &= (x-1) \, \ln(4) \\
x \, (\ln(3) - \ln(4)) &= - \ln(2^{2}) = - 2 \, \ln(2) \\
x &= - \frac{2 \, \ln(2)}{\ln\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}
\end{align}

Converting from natural logarithm to a base 10 logarithm:

Use 
$$\log_{b}(x) = \frac{\log_{d}(x)}{\log_{d}(b)}$$
to convert the base of the logarithms. Here, let $b = e$ and $d = 10$ to yield
\begin{align}
x = - 2 \, \cdot \frac{\log_{10}(2)}{\log_{10}(e)} \, \frac{\log_{10}(e)}{\log_{10}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)} = -2 \, \frac{\log_{10}(2)}{\log_{10}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}.
\end{align}

Strictly solving by base 10 logarithm:
\begin{align}
\log_{10}(3^{y}) &= \log_{10}(4^{y-1}) \\
y \, \log_{10}(3) &= y \, \log_{10}(4) - \log_{10}(4) \\
y \, (\log_{10}(3) - \log_{10}(4)) &= - \log_{10}(4) \\
y &= \frac{- \, \log_{10}(4)}{\log_{10}(3) - \log_{10}(4)} = \frac{2 \, \log_{10}(2)}{\log_{10}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}.
\end{align}

Comment: I want the value of $x$ in terms of $ln2$ and $ln3$ only.

Comment: @RaviPrakash: then this should be mentioned when you ask the problem.

Comment: you can simplify the expression above to get what you want pretty easily;
remember that $$ln(4) = ln(2^2) = 2ln(2)$$

Comment: Don't re-use the value $x$ in your formula starting the base $10$ case, it is apt to be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Whichever base $b$ you use for the logarithm, we have
$$
\log_b(a^k) = k \log_b(a)
$$
for any $a,k$.  Take a logarithm of both sides of your equation.